# JavaScript live search in table show also higher row

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following, working, code to search in an HTML table with JavaScript, highlight the results and hide not matching rows:

```js
'use strict';

;
(function($, window, document, undefined) {
  var $container = $('.main');
  if (!$container.length) return true;

  var $input = $container.find('input'),
    $notfound = $container.find('.notfound'),
    $items = $container.find(' > table > tbody > tr'),
    $item = $(),
    itemsIndexed = [];

  $items.each(function() {
    itemsIndexed.push($(this).text().replace(/\s{2,}/g, ' ').toLowerCase());
  });

  $input.on('keyup', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) // enter
    {
      $input.trigger('blur');
      return true;
    }

    $items.each(function() {
      $item = $(this);
      $item.html($item.html().replace(/<span class="highlight">([^<]+)<\/span>/gi, '$1'));
    });

    var searchVal = $.trim($input.val()).toLowerCase();
    if (searchVal.length) {
      for (var i in itemsIndexed) {
        $item = $items.eq(i);
        if (itemsIndexed[i].indexOf(searchVal) != -1)
          $item.removeClass('is-hidden').html($item.html().replace(new RegExp(searchVal + '(?!([^<]+)?>)', 'gi'), '<span class="highlight">$&</span>'));
        else
          $item.addClass('is-hidden');
      }
    } else $items.removeClass('is-hidden');

    $notfound.toggleClass('is-visible', $items.not('.is-hidden').length == 0);
  });
})(jQuery, window, document);
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: #fffd77;
}

.is-hidden {
  display: none;
}

.notfound {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}

.notfound.is-visible {
  display: block;
}

.boldtitle {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
}

.table_details {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <input autofocus="" style="width:95%;height:40px;font-size:20px;margin-bottom:5px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;display:block;" type="search" value="">

  <table>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3" class="left">
        <p class="boldtitle">Cars</p>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="left"><a class="table_details" href="http://www.example.com">GM</a><span class="link_company">GM</span></td>
      <td class="middle">XXXXXXXXXX</td>
      <td class="right">YYYYYYYYYY<br></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="left"><a class="table_details" href="http://www.example.com">VW</a><span class="link_company">VW</span></td>
      <td class="middle">XXXXXXXXXX</td>
      <td class="right">YYYYYYYYYY<br></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="left"><a class="table_details" href="http://www.example.com">Opel</a><span class="link_company">Opel</span></td>
      <td class="middle">XXXXXXXXXX</td>
      <td class="right">YYYYYYYYYY<br></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="left"><a class="table_details" href="http://www.example.com">BMW</a><span class="link_company">BMW</span></td>
      <td class="middle">XXXXXXXXXX</td>
      <td class="right">YYYYYYYYYY<br></td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
      <td colspan="3" class="left">
        <p class="boldtitle">Fruits</p>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="left"><a class="table_details" href="http://www.example.com">Apple</a><span class="link_company">Apple</span></td>
      <td class="middle">XXXXXXXXXX</td>
      <td class="right">YYYYYYYYYY<br></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="left"><a class="table_details" href="http://www.example.com">Banana</a><span class="link_company">Banana</span></td>
      <td class="middle">XXXXXXXXXX</td>
      <td class="right">YYYYYYYYYY<br></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="left"><a class="table_details" href="http://www.example.com">Plump</a><span class="link_company">Plump</span></td>
      <td class="middle">XXXXXXXXXX</td>
      <td class="right">YYYYYYYYYY<br></td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
      <td colspan="3" class="left">
        <p class="boldtitle">Names</p>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="left"><a class="table_details" href="http://www.example.com">George</a><span class="link_company">George</span></td>
      <td class="middle">XXXXXXXXXX</td>
      <td class="right">YYYYYYYYYY<br></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="left"><a class="table_details" href="http://www.example.com">Harry</a><span class="link_company">Harry</span></td>
      <td class="middle">XXXXXXXXXX</td>
      <td class="right">YYYYYYYYYY<br></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="left"><a class="table_details" href="http://www.example.com">Peter</a><span class="link_company">Peter</span></td>
      <td class="middle">XXXXXXXXXX</td>
      <td class="right">YYYYYYYYYY<br></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="left"><a class="table_details" href="http://www.example.com">David</a><span class="link_company">David</span></td>
      <td class="middle">XXXXXXXXXX</td>
      <td class="right">YYYYYYYYYY<br></td>
    </tr>
  </table>


  <div class="notfound">Nothing found!</div>

</div>
```

What I want to reach: Actually when I search for e.g. `Apple`, I'm getting this:

[image]

But I would like to have the title, in this case `Fruits`, shown, too, like this:

[image]

Comment: Why would you undo the edits I made that made your code example runnable and your images embedded??

Comment: Try [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/julmot/bs69vcqL/) using [mark.js](https://markjs.io/).